# Calculating values from two tables where one has key in header and one has it in column values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple problem that I dont know how to solve in sql.

I have two tables, 
cost :

```
     a |  b    |  c
-------+-------+---------------
 31.99 | 14.12 | 133.1
```

second table: income

```
Party | sum
------+--------
  A   |  90
  B   |  12
  C   |  70
```

Now i want to get a result that substract for each party `A, B, C` the income-cost and finds the net value. I cannot compare the column header to column value. I am quite new to this, so I am struggling quite a lot. There should be really easy way of doing this.

I created the 'cost' table by

```
 SELECT sum(A) as A, sum(B) as B, sum(C)  as C FROM mytable;
```

may be there is clever way of creating this table in the same formate as income table that would make it easier to compare? I will appreciate any suggeestion on any of the two fronts. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare, using `case`:

```
select party,
       cost - (case when party = 'a' then a
                    when party = 'b' then b
                    when party = 'c' then c
               else 0 end)
from cost c cross join
     income i
```

Comment: Should use simplified `CASE`, EG: `CASE party WHEN 'A' THEN A WHEN 'B' THEN B WHEN 'C' THEN C ELSE 0 END`

Comment: @Gordon this is great! It works perfect! I have a question on this. How does it automatically go for the row value with the use of `case`? `Case` is giving 'a' or 'b' or 'c' column but in case there was more than 1 row in the income table, then this would not work, would it? Also do you have any suggestion for my other question on how to create similar table for cost that looks like income table (row and column transposed from query) ? Thank you very much for your help! You made my day ! :)

Comment: @hadik . . . Each row has a different value of `party`.  So, only one expression is used per row.